# How my server is listened on port 3000,without adding the code for server.listen( ), Using Express Generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Does Express application, Created by Express Generator automatically listens on port no. 3000 by default

I Don't think I have no where included code for listening the server

is code for listening the port is added by default, when we use express Generator.

Answer (score 0):

In index.js are the settings you can set the port...

app.listen(3000);

Default is 3000